# Intellij IDEA 9: How can I disable the inspection error when using a 'with' clause in HQL?

Tags: intellij-idea

How do you resolve an Intellij V9 inspection error of 'WHERE, GROUP BY, HAVING or ORDER BY expected' on the following HQL string: 
  select a from ObjA a inner join a.column b **with b.variable=:bvar** where a.variable=:avar

Answer (score 2):

It's not an inspection, but a result of code parsing. A solution would be to disable this particular Language Injection in Settings.

Comment: While this removed the error message, I'm still seeking for a solution that doesn't involve removal of these kind of settings.

Comment: @RonnieKilsbo, you can vote for [this request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-106481).